# Lucene TextField not tokenized

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

I am saving the following title to index

```
doc.add(new TextField(TITLE, "Button",Field.Store.YES ));
```

Then when I search for it with say "butto", nothing returns. I must search for "button" to get anything back. What do I have to do so that any substring of button gives a result? I am using

```
 StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `StandardAnalyzer` creates just the token `button` for the input text and so, only a query for `button` matches the document.
To search for any substring of button, you have two options.

At search-time, you can use a different query, e.g. a [PrefixQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html) or a [WildcardQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html). If you use the query parser, you can use `butto?` or `butto*`.

At index-time, you can use a different analyzer, that emits substrings as tokens, for example the [EdgeNGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenizer.html) which would emit `[bu, but, butt, butto, button]` based on the configuration; or the [NGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html), which would emit `[bu, ut, tt, to, on]` and so on for the configured size(s).